# Calling member function of a TypeScript class compiles but throw 'TypeError: statistics.addRatingStatistic is not a function'

Tags: typescript

I try to use TypeScript but I if I call a method on my class I get in Chrome's console this `error: TypeError: statistics.addRatingStatistic is not a function`.

My interface and class are the following:

```
  export interface RatingStatisctics {
  1: number;
  2: number;
  3: number;
  4: number;
  5: number;

  addRatingStatistic(nnewElem: number, addition: boolean): void;
}

export class RatingStatisticsImpl implements RatingStatisctics {
  1: number;
  2: number;
  3: number;
  4: number;
  5: number;

  constructor() {
    this[1] = 0;
    this[2] = 0;
    this[3] = 0;
    this[4] = 0;
    this[5] = 0;
  }

  addRatingStatistic(newElem: number, addition: boolean): void {
    const change: number = addition ? 1 : -1;
    switch (newElem) {
      case 1:
        this[1] = this[1] + change;
        break;
      case 2:
        this[2] = this[2] + change;
        break;
      case 3:
        this[3] = this[3] + change;
        break;
      case 4:
        this[4] = this[4] + change;
        break;
      case 5:
        this[5] = this[5] + change;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried with 'public' keyword in the implementing class before the function.

I call it like this:

```
const statistics: RatingStatisctics = modifiedOffer.rating_statistics;
statistics.addRatingStatistic(newRating.rating, true);
```

If I outsource the function into a helper class like this it works:

```
addRatingStatistic(statistics: RatingStatisctics, newElem: number, addition: boolean): void {
    const change: number = addition ? 1 : -1;
    switch (newElem) {
      case 1:
        statistics[1] = statistics[1] + change;
        break;
      case 2:
        statistics[2] = statistics[2] + change;
        break;
      case 3:
        statistics[3] = statistics[3] + change;
        break;
      case 4:
        statistics[4] = statistics[4] + change;
        break;
      case 5:
        statistics[5] = statistics[5] + change;
        break;
    }
  }
```

My question is, why does it not work in the class?

Thanks

Comment: Besides that spelling errors in code are a no no, makes me not want to read it... :) you do not show what `modifiedOffer.rating_statistics` is, nor you show the call to the "outsourced" function that you say works.  Overall, you should provide the proverbial Minimal, Reproducible Example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally something one can copy paste to a playground and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do [edit] the code here to be a [mre] so we can get started helping.  Otherwise the question lacks debugging details we need.

Comment: I will update it soon, thanks for the feedback.